# Pomodoro Clock giving negative values

Tags: javascript, jquery

Created a Pomodoro Clock using JavaScript. 
It works fine, but once it gets to the break timer, and for everything after that, it gives me a negative time between seconds.

https://jsfiddle.net/3fehu668/

JavaScript:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var clock = $("#clock");
    var heading = $("h1");
    var breakMinus = $("#break-minus");
    var breakPlus = $("#break-plus");
    var sessionMinus = $("#session-minus");
    var sessionPlus = $("#session-plus");
    var breakTime = $("#break-time");
    var sessionTime = $("#session-time");
    var startButton = $("#start-btn");
    var resetButton = $("#reset-btn");
    var breakVal = parseInt(breakTime.val());
    var sessionVal = parseInt(sessionTime.val());

    breakMinus.on("click", function(){
        if (breakVal > 0) {
            breakVal--;
            breakTime.val(breakVal);
        }
    });

    breakPlus.on("click", function(){
        breakVal++;
        breakTime.val(breakVal);
    });

    sessionMinus.on("click", function(){
        if (sessionVal > 0) {
            sessionVal--;
            sessionTime.val(sessionVal);
        }
    });

    sessionPlus.on("click", function(){
        sessionVal++;
        sessionTime.val(sessionVal);
    });

    startButton.on("click", function(){
        if (valuesEntered()) {
            var finalTime = sessionVal * 60 + getTimeInSeconds();
            heading.html("Session running!");
            setInterval(function(){startTime(getTimeInSeconds(), finalTime)}, 1000);
        }
    });

    breakTime.on("input", function(){
        breakVal = parseInt(breakTime.val());
    });

    sessionTime.on("input", function(){
        sessionVal = parseInt(sessionTime.val());
    });

    function valuesEntered(){
        console.log("breakVal = " + breakVal);
        console.log("sessionVal = " + sessionVal);
        if (breakVal < 0 || sessionVal < 0) {
            alert("Time can't be negative! Check your inputs!");
        } else if (breakVal === 0 || sessionVal === 0){
            alert("Please enter a time for your break and session! (Time can't be 0)");
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    function startTime(currentTime, finalTime){
        console.log("Setting timer...");
        setTime(currentTime, finalTime);
        if(finalTime === getTimeInSeconds()){
            alert("Time for a break!");
            heading.html("Break!");
            finalTime = breakVal * 60 + currentTime;
            clearTimer();
            setInterval(function(){startBreak(getTimeInSeconds(), finalTime)}, 1000);
        }
    }

    function clearTimer() {
        var intervalID = window.setInterval("", 9999); // get reference to last interval + 1
        clearInterval(intervalID - 1);
    }

    function startBreak(currentTime, finalTime){
        console.log("Break time...");
        setTime(currentTime, finalTime);
        if(finalTime === getTimeInSeconds()){
            alert("Back to work!");
            heading.html("Session running!");
            finalTime = sessionVal * 60 + currentTime;
            clearTimer();
            setInterval(function(){startTime(getTimeInSeconds(), finalTime)}, 1000);
        }

    }

    function setTime(currentTime, finalTime){
        console.log("Setting the time. Current Time = " + getTimeInSeconds() + ",  FinalTime = " + finalTime);
        var minutes = Math.floor((finalTime - currentTime) / 60);
        var seconds = (finalTime - currentTime) % 60;
        if (minutes < 10) {
            minutes = "0" + minutes;
        }
        if (seconds < 10) {
            seconds = "0" + seconds;
        }
        clock.html(minutes  + ":" + seconds);
    }

    function getTimeInSeconds() {
        var date = new Date();
        return date.getMinutes() * 60 + date.getSeconds();
    }
});
```

I'm not posting the HTML and CSS code because I don't think its relevant. You can find it in the jsfiddle though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting negative values because after completion of `work timer`, your `clearInterval` is not actually clearing out your timer. Now, your previous timer is already set and `break timer` is also initialized due to which both are running simultaneously and setting values.`finaltime` is already reached when break timer is set so negative values are coming.

One more thing convert `milliseconds` to seconds in `getTimeInSeconds()`. Suppose, present time is `15:59:40` and you are starting the timer for `1 minute` then what will happen is something different. For first `20` seconds it will run good but after that your minutes resets to `0` and this will set your minutes to `60` your are setting timer for `1 minute` but end up with `60 minutes`.

One more thing in equality check condition

```
if(finalTime === getTimeInSeconds()){
}
```

you are setting `finalTime` using `finalTime = sessionVal * 60 + currentTime` it works but you are setting alert dialog box. Suppose , someone click ok after `5 seconds` now your timer won't run for `60 seconds` instead runs for `55 seconds` because 5 seconds are already elapsed. Don't know how you want your time to process after clicking alert whether to start time after clicking or just go on as it is going . just telling.

Here is your updated jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3fehu668/3/